# Plotting two sets of MultiVariate Gaussian Data on the same plot

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, gaussian

I am trying to create and plot two sets of Gaussian Data. I have used numpy np.random.multivariate_normal(mu, cov, #points).T format. When I don't transpose, it gives me a "too many values to unpack (expected 2) error.

At any rate, when I do transpose, I can successfully plot one set of data. My goal is to create two of these sets, and show them on the same plot. With a given set of data, I can simply just plt.scatter(data1) and plt.scatter(data2), however that same processes does not work for this problem.

Below is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

mu_first = [1, 1]
mu_second = [-1, -1]
cov_first = [[0.025, 0.0], [0.0, 0.025]]
cov_second = [[0.025, 0.0], [0.0, 0.025]]

x1,y1 = np.random.multivariate_normal(mu_first, cov_first, 10000)
x2,y2 = np.random.multivariate_normal(mu_second, cov_second, 10000).T

plt.plot(x1,y1,'r')
plt.plot(x2,y2,'b')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add transpose because when you want assign to elements of an array to two variables, the array shape must be `(2,n)`. But when you do not add transpose, the shape of array would be `(n,2)`. So you get `too many values to unpack`.

About scatter plot, in `plt.scatter()`, third argument is for size of points, then 'r' or 'b' are wrong choices.

So your code should be like bellow:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

mu_first = [1, 1]
mu_second = [-1, -1]
cov_first = [[0.025, 0.0], [0.0, 0.025]]
cov_second = [[0.025, 0.0], [0.0, 0.025]]

x1,y1 = np.random.multivariate_normal(mu_first, cov_first, 10000).T
x2,y2 = np.random.multivariate_normal(mu_second, cov_second, 10000).T

plt.scatter(x1,y1,c='r')
plt.scatter(x2,y2,c='b')
plt.show()
```

Output plot:

[image]

Comment: You could additionally set some transparency and use smaller dots. E.g. `plt.scatter(x1, y1, color='r', alpha=0.2, s=1)`